# Splitting string with search phrases

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

I want to split this string:

```
large "red pill"
```

into this array of substrings:

```
arr(0) = "large"
arr(1) = "red pill"
```

How can I achieve this easily?

Comment: Show me what the string look like when you assign it to a variable in code.

Comment: What you're asking is not necessarily trivial. What you're essentially asking is "how do I split a string on adverbs." One solution is to know the adverbs ahead of time, but with this you limit yourself to the values in your collection of adverbs. Alternatively you would need to create a parser to parse English sentences, which can be very difficult because of all the variations in the English language (e.g. it isn't a formal language).

Comment: @David Do you mean adjectives? Both red and large are adjectives.

Comment: @Mary - probably so, I failed English (twice) when I was in high school.

Answer (score 0):

I have just made this quick and dirty solution and it works fine for my purpose

```
Dim List As New ArrayList
Dim Idx, Idx2 As Integer

Do
    Idx = str.IndexOf("""")
    If Idx >= 0 And str.Length > Idx + 1 Then
        Idx2 = str.IndexOf("""", Idx + 1)
        If Idx2 > 0 Then
           List.Add(str.Substring(Idx + 1, Idx2 - Idx - 1).Trim)
           str = str.Remove(Idx, Idx2 - Idx + 1)
        End If
    End If
Loop Until Idx = -1

For Each w As String In str.Split(" ")
    If w.Trim <> "" Then
        List.Add(w.Trim)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: No ArrayList in new code. Use List(Of T). In this case List(Of String)

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you can split by double quotes

```
Dim quotes As Char() = { """"c }
Dim text As String = "large ""red pill"""

Dim phrases As String() = text.
    Split(quotes, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
    Select(Function(phrase) phrase.Trim()).
    ToArray()

Dim output As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, phrases)
Console.WriteLine (output)

' Output:
' [0] - large
' [1] - red pill
```

For cases where string can contain multiple "single words" separated by space you can split by double quotes first, then split by empty space and combine all phrases into one array

```
Dim quotes As Char() = { """"c }
Dim spaces As Char() = { " "c }   
Dim text As String = "large ""red pill"" small medium ""yellow stone"""

Dim result = text.Split(quotes, StringSplitOptions.None).
    SelectMany(Function(phrase, index)
        If index Mod 2 = 0 Then           
            Return phrase.Split(spaces, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)            
        Else
            Return { phrase }
        End If
    End Function)

Dim output As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result)
Console.WriteLine (output)

' Output:
' [0] - large
' [1] - red pill
' [2] - small
' [3] - medium
' [4] - yellow stone
```